# haskell - optimizing AVL tree

Tags: haskell, optimization, avl-tree

as a part of learning haskell i decided to implement an AVL tree. as of now, i only implemented insertion.

the implementation works, but it performs 3-4 times slower than a random java implementation i found for a random list of 9999999 random numbers.

it performs almost as well when given an input list of `[1..9999999]` or `[9999999..1]` (descending or ascending list), so i think the problem may lie in the `rl` and `lr` rolls

i would appreciate any hint about how to make it run faster.

yes, i know it looks kind of ugly.

```
data Tree a =   Empty |
                Branch {    key     :: a,
                            balance :: Int,
                            left    :: Tree a,
                            right   :: Tree a,
                            up      :: Bool    
                          --used internally to stop updating balance
                       }
                deriving (Eq)

leaf :: (Ord a, Eq a) => a -> Tree a
leaf x = Branch x 0 Empty Empty True

-- insert ------------------------------------
treeInsert :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
treeInsert Empty x  = leaf x
treeInsert (Branch y b l r _) x 
  | x < y =
    let nl@(Branch _ _ _ _ nlu) = treeInsert l x   -- nl = new left
    in
      if nlu
        then if b==1  
               then roll $ Branch y  2      nl r False 
               else        Branch y (b + 1) nl r (b /= (-1)) 
        else               Branch y  b      nl r False
  | x > y = 
    let nr@(Branch _ _ _ _ nru) = treeInsert r x   -- nr = new right
    in
      if nru 
        then if b==(-1) 
               then roll $ Branch y (-2)    l nr False 
               else        Branch y (b - 1) l nr (b /= 1) 
        else               Branch y  b      l nr False
  | otherwise =            Branch x  b      l r  False

-- rolls -------------------------------------
roll :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Tree a -> Tree a
-- ll roll
roll (Branch y 2 (Branch ly 1 ll lr _) r _) = 
            Branch ly  0 ll (Branch y 0 lr r False) False
-- rr roll
roll (Branch y (-2) l (Branch ry (-1) rl rr _) _) = 
            Branch ry  0 (Branch y 0 l rl False) rr False
-- lr rolls
roll (Branch y 2 (Branch ly (-1) ll (Branch lry lrb lrl lrr _) _) r _) = 
   case lrb of 
     0  ->  Branch lry 0 (Branch ly 0   ll  lrl False) 
                         (Branch y  0   lrr r   False) False
     1  ->  Branch lry 0 (Branch ly 0   ll  lrl False) 
                         (Branch y (-1) lrr r   False) False
     (-1)-> Branch lry 0 (Branch ly 1   ll  lrl False) 
                         (Branch y  0   lrr r   False) False
-- rl rolls
roll (Branch y (-2) l (Branch ry 1 (Branch rly rlb rll rlr _) rr _) _) = 
   case rlb of 
     0  ->  Branch rly 0 (Branch y  0   l   rll False) 
                         (Branch ry 0   rlr rr  False) False
     1  ->  Branch rly 0 (Branch y  0   l   rll False) 
                         (Branch ry (-1) rlr rr False) False
     (-1)-> Branch rly 0 (Branch y  1   l   rll False) 
                         (Branch ry 0   rlr rr  False) False

-- construct a tree --------------------------
construct :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Tree a -> [a] -> Tree a
construct = foldl' treeInsert

-- rands -------------------------------------
rands :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
rands n low high seed = take n $ randomRs (low, high) (mkStdGen seed)

-- test run
main = do
    seed <- round `fmap` getPOSIXTime
    let ma = 9999999
    let t = construct Empty ( rands ma 1 ma seed ) 
    start <- getPOSIXTime
    end <- t `seq` getPOSIXTime
    print (end - start)
```

Comment: How are you compiling the program, what flags? And which version of GHC please?

Comment: latest ghc, eclipsefp only put -wall in flags, didn't add any other.

Comment: It is possible, even likely, that the Java implementation you are comparing with has different functionality: namely, that it does not support sharing and instead mutates node values. It doesn't make much sense to compare appels and oranges, though.

Comment: Start by using: `ghc -O2`

Comment: not seeing any noticeable difference using -O2

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps if you show the java implementation, there will be some basis for analysis.

Comment: @n.m. https://github.com/justinethier/AVL-Tree/blob/master/AvlTree.java

Comment: @Ingo what do you mean by "does not support sharing"?

Comment: @jajdoo - When you insert a value in your tree, you get a new tree, while keeping the old one (if you want). The new tree and the old tree share data, for example, the right branch, when your insert went to the left branch. While your java version (as I thought) mutates the tree. Hence you always have only one valid tree. In that case, the question of sharing is menaingless, of course.

Comment: The profiler says `roll` is not a problem...

Comment: @WillNess - I was wondering about the activity on that repo... now it makes sense :)

Comment: @n.m. what the profiler says apart from this?

Comment: @WillNess if i post this on code review should i change the question in some way (apart from any new info i added in comment)?

Comment: @jajdoo if your code is working; if you use it in real project and want it reviewed then I guess it fits there as is (please don't post it in your original formatting <:-> ); but I'm in no way an authority on meta stuff. If you would add here links to working Ideone entries for both Haskell and Java (or at least Java), maybe someone would find it easier to check this out here as well. CodeReview has very low traffic.

Comment: Nothing too encouraging. `treeInsert` itself is the major CPU hog (about 3/4 of all time). Most of the rest is random number generation (haven't looked at it closely) Note I have reduced the problem size tenfold, my computer is too weak to handle the full size. You can profile yourself, ghc has all the tools included by default.

Comment: i just don't get why it will work almost as well for an ordered list but 4 times as bad for an unordered one.. perhaps haskell is re-evaluating subtrees it already evaluated previously after rolls?