# Is there any way to expose the hidden package haskell98 from a source code pragma in ghc-7.6.3?

Tags: haskell

Ideone.com has recently switched to ghc-7.6.3 where `haskell98` is a hidden package.

To expose a hidden package the `-package` flag is supposed to be used, but it is listed as "static". `OPTIONS_GHC` is supposed to only recognize "dynamic" flags and indeed, [trying `-package haskell98` inside the source code pragma doesn't work](http://ideone.com/vEHOXV).

Specifically, I'm trying to run a code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182507/haskell-optimizing-avl-tree), which contains calls to `randomRs`. `System.Random` is no longer included with 7.6.3 apparently, whereas `Random` is a part of the hidden `haskell98` package. There is also the dynamic `-no-auto-link-packages` flag which means *"Don't automatically link in the haskell98 package"* but it's the opposite of what I need.

Comment: You can't just use the `random` package?

Comment: `System.Random` is a part of Haskell Platform.

http://www.haskell.org/platform/ 

Last HP is 2013.2.0.0, including GHC 7.6.3

Comment: I'd expect `{-# LANGUAGE Haskell98 #-}` to un-hide the package, since those modules are part of that standard. But it doesn't, so maybe that's a ghc bug.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I tried to import System.Random but it came back with "Could not find module `System.Random`". And [package `random` on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1) only mentions 7.4.

Comment: @wit I have no control over what Ideone.com is using in their installation.

Comment: @WillNess You need to `cabal install random` to get the random package.  It is between you and Ideone to get packages installed - most languages are pretty useless beyond learning without access to their package databases.  Also, it doesn't matter what is mentioned on hackage - build tests just happen with whatever is available at the time the package is uploaded.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson ideone.com is a very handy online compiler, useful for if you're _away from a computer you have control over_. There's no way ideone.com is going to let you run command line programs, and it's sensible that they don't provide the entire contents of hackage.

Comment: @AndrewC the point is, I don't see any way to run *anything* from haskell98 package on 7.6.3 without having to use command line, not just Random. Maybe GHC should provide some way to unhide it from the source code pragmas, or some special dynamic flag. Why there's a `-no-auto-link-packages` but no `-do-auto-link-packages`?..

Comment: @AndrewC Ideone is very handy for publishing runnable code snippets, with timings.

Comment: @WillNess I completely agree with everything you've said on this question. +2 if I make a sockpuppet one day, +1 for now.

Comment: @AndrewC appreciate it. :) I left a note to Ideone.com urging them to add `-package haskell98` to their command line, and the link to this question. If maybe more people would do the same, they'd know it's really needed. ;) ;) But I also hoped that someone might know the way, like with `{-# LANGUAGE Haskell98 #-}` - which sadly didn't work either. Maybe it's an oversight on part of GHC developers too?