# Random Data with Haskell in ideone.com

Tags: haskell, random

I'm playing with Haskell on [ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com), and failed to run a program that uses randomness.

Several tutorials suggest that I use `System.Random`, but this one doesn't exist in Haskell 7.6.3, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18278254/1111371) also says. From comments there, importing `System.Random` seems hopeless.

I'm willing to use any mechanism for randomness. If `System.Random` is deprecated, I'm actually happy to learn the replacement. But what is it?

I saw `Control.Monad.Random` mentioned, but importing it in ideone also fails.

I implemented [Randall Munroe's RNG](http://xkcd.com/221/), but it's quite unsatisfactory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Random` isn't deprecated, but moved to its own [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1). It is no longer part of GHC, but it is included in the Haskell Platform and still considered an important module.

I don't think there is much you can do, except ask the people running ideone to include it.

You could also roll your own pseudo random monad and provide the seed value by hand, but that isn't very satisfactory either and probably way more effort than getting your own haskell dev environment.

Comment: I suggest you ask the ideone people to add both the `random` and `MonadRandom` classes. These are both important modules. Even though they're not part of GHC per se, they're the de facto standard for doing "random" stuff in Haskell.

Comment: So bottom line - there's no source of randomness built-in in GHC?

Comment: @ugoren This is correct.  There is no source of randomness built into most compilers for that matter.

Comment: @ugoren: As far as I can tell that's exactly right. And why would it? It's a compiler, not a complete programming suite. That's the job that the Haskell Platform was created for.